# Error with simple_form and active_attr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form, active-attr

I am using active_attr and simple_form.

When I navigate to the page that should show my form I get the following error:

```
undefined method `new_record?' for #<Message body: nil, email: nil, name: nil, subject: nil>
```

Here is my model:

```
class Message

  include ActiveAttr::Model

  attribute :name
  attribute :email
  attribute :subject
  attribute :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

end
```

My Controller:

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @message = Message.new
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

And finally my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @message, :url => contact_path do |f| %> 
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.input :subject %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :wrapped, :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the extra functionality I included to make a wrapped button for twitter bootstrap as found on https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Twitter-Bootstrap-v2-and-simple_form-v2 broke it.

Answer (score 0):

This error was due to a bug in active_attr that was fixed in v0.7.0. Upgrading resolves the issue.